# How do I create a relation that has both global and specific assignments?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a model in my application (we can call it Agent) that has a many-to-many relation with model Mission (a model representing a mission that may be assigned to one or more agents)
a mission can be accepted by an agent:

```
class Agent < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :assignments
    has_many :missions, :through => :assignments
end

class Assignment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :agent
    belongs_to :mission

    attr_accessible :accepted
end

class Mission < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :assignments
    has_many :agents, :through => :assignments
end
```

Now I want to be able to create missions that are assigned to all agents at once with the following requirements:

1. A "global" mission is assigned to all Agents, but can be accepted be each separately
2. "global" missions apply also to Agents that are created after the global mission was created.
3. I don't want to create new Assignment models each time a new Agent is created (in order to assign him all the global missions) and I don't want to create assignments for all existing Agents every time a new global mission is created.
4. An existing mission that was assigned to a specific (or multiple) agents, can be easily converted to a global mission.
5. Given an agent, I want to get all his assignments (global and specific) in a single call and if possible, as a relation and not an array

What would be a good design (both db and models) to achieve this functionality without creating separate tables for global and non-global missions?

Thanks!

Ariel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just add an is_global flag to the Mission.

Then when you're fetching a list of missions to accept you would just look for all missions that have an assignment to the specific agent and have not been accepted, plus all global missions that are not assigned to the specific agent.

When the agent accepts the global mission, create the assignment record and set accepted to true.

If an agent can remove him/herself from a mission then just destroy the assignment record.

**Fetch all missions**

You will need to enhance fetching all available missions to look at two distinct cases. The first case is a mission that is assigned, and the second case is a mission that is global but not assigned.

```
Mission.includes(:assignments)
        .where("missions.is_global = true or assignments.agent_id = ?", agent_id)
```

I don't have a ruby env readily available to test but if that's not correct it's close :)

**Bonus**

You can query for all assignments without caring if an assignment is global or regular.

```
assignments = agent.ssignments.where(accepted:true)
```

**Update**

If my query doesn't work for you or if you want to go another route there are always other solutions online, and the [meta where](https://github.com/ernie/meta_where) or [squeel](https://github.com/ernie/squeel) gems can help you.

Comment: This is quite complicated (and is actually my current solution, sorry I didn't mention it above). It means that I can't get all my missions through any of the relations (assignments will only have global missions that were accepted but it will have all the specific missions). In addition, doing agent1.assignments or agent1.missions will return inconsistent results (for missions that were non-global but were made global, as well as for global missions that were accepted)

Comment: You will have to modify your query to include global unassigned missions. I will update my answer.